# How to redirect unauthenticated without flashing the page ? NEXTJS

Tags: authentication, redirect, next.js, jwt

after many attemps i've could set my admin auth for the pages, now im fighting with not showing partially for a second the admin dashboard before redirecting.

Here is the code i have . I have no idea on how to do it... i've tried many things, nothing works.

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router"
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import useSWR from 'swr';
import axios from "../lib/axios";


export const useAuth = ({ middleware } = {}) => {
    const router = useRouter();

    // LOADING
    const [isLoading, setisLoading] = useState(true);

    // USER
    const { data: user, error, mutate } = useSWR('/api/user', () =>
        axios
            .get('/api/user')
            .then(res => res.data)
            .catch(error => {
                if (error.response.status !== 401) throw error

                router.push('/')
            }),
    )

    // CSRF
    const csrf = () => axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie'); // IS BASED TOKEN, I DONT KNOW HOW TO CHANGE IT.

    // LOGOUT

    const logout = async () => {
        await axios.post('/api/logout');
        mutate(null);
        router.push("/login");
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (user || error) {
            setisLoading(false);
        }

        if (middleware == "guest" && user) router.push("/");
        if (middleware == "auth" && error) router.push("/login");


    })

    return {

        user,
        csrf,
        logout,
        isLoading

    }
}
```

This is what i got and it works when trying to protect the routes, btw i have token based authentication not cookies.

Now i want to know how to avoid that flashing dashboard before redirect. I think it should be with useEffect, so i've tried this thing but doesn't works. Any info would be helpful thanks :D

```
  useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`/api/user`).then(res => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                console.log('nice');
            }
            setLoading(false);
        });
    }, []);

    axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, function axiosRetryInterceptor(err) {
        if (err.response.status === 401) {
            router.push('/');
        }
        return Promise.reject(err);
    });
```

Comment: I think is using some kind of use effect or something

Comment: If you're checking the user's authenticated state on the client-side there's no way around the flash/loading. For that you'll  have to verify the user on the server-side instead. See https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication#authenticating-server-rendered-pages.